# Problem for check if sql request return a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, discord.js

I haver this request :

```
const sqlConfig = {
              password: MSSQLPASSWORD,
              database: MSSQLDBTANK1,
              stream: false,
              options: {
                trustServerCertificate: true,             
                enableArithAbort: true,
                encrypt: true
              },
              port: 1433,
              user: MSSQLUSER,
              server: MSSQLIP,
            }
          
            sql.connect(sqlConfig)
              .then(async (pool) => {

             var selectQuery = "SELECT distinct * FROM Active_Number (NOLOCK)INNER JOIN Sys_Users_Detail (NOLOCK) ON Active_Number.UserID = Sys_Users_Detail.UserID WHERE   Active_Number.ActiveID = 80004 AND Sys_Users_Detail.UserName = '"+username+"'";
              return pool.request().query(selectQuery);

              })


              .then('error', err => {
                console.log('You have already voted 1');
            })

              .then((result) =>
              {

                console.log('You have already voted 2');

              })
```

How to make for count returned result.
Because i need check if sq lrequest is correct.

Can you help me please ?

I have discord js and mssql

THX

Execute DB and every time i have a result

Comment: do you JUST want to get the number of returned rows ?

Comment: Yes, for test if request return a value.

For test if is true is :

`
 .then((result) =>
              {
})
`

But if i enter a no valid username it work ...

Comment: so something like if returned value (rows qty) > 0 then something and if value =0 then username does not exist then bla bla bla

Comment: How to check if request sql return result or not ? 

Please

Comment: did it work ? i hope so

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack. Its in the query. This can be exploited by attackers to make malicious SQL queries. It happens because you concatenate `username` to the query. Lets say `username` is `'; DROP TABLE Active_Number;` This will trick your code into sending it to the database, which will execute it, and delete your table. To fix this you can sanitize your code, or better use an ORM. ORM's will make secure queries for you automatically, and if you want to use pure SQL, then most of them have options to sanitize the queries. I personally use Prisma https://prisma.io

Answer (score 0):

Just query the recordset lenght **result.rowsAffected** when getting (or not) rows from the db. If you want to dig further [check this out](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#affected-rows).

Something like this should work:

```
const sqlConfig = {
              password: MSSQLPASSWORD,
              database: MSSQLDBTANK1,
              stream: false,
              options: {
                trustServerCertificate: true,             
                enableArithAbort: true,
                encrypt: true
              },
              port: 1433,
              user: MSSQLUSER,
              server: MSSQLIP,
            }

      
        sql.connect(sqlConfig)
          .then(async (pool) => {

         var selectQuery = "SELECT distinct * FROM Active_Number (NOLOCK)INNER JOIN Sys_Users_Detail (NOLOCK) ON Active_Number.UserID = Sys_Users_Detail.UserID WHERE   Active_Number.ActiveID = 80004 AND Sys_Users_Detail.UserName = '"+username+"'";
          return pool.request().query(selectQuery);

          }).then(result => {
     //result.rowsAffected has the value you are looking for 
    console.dir(result.rowsAffected)
}).catch(err => {
  // ... error checks
});
```

Comment: THX but how to make for one INSERT ?

Comment: you explicitly referred to a Select, what is the logic for insert? do you want to have it stick to the select  ? please then provide some code and/or logic